# Access old version of file

Tags: centos, deleted-files

I was working on a file locally in Notepad++ and uploaded it via FTP to server - during the upload something went wrong without me realising and the uploaded file is now empty (size shows as 0).

I have checked for a cache/backup in Notepad++ and it doesn't exist so is there any way via Centos command line to access the old versions of the file?

I have a backup from last night which I can recover to but it means I lose all the work I did today which is a major pain so am hoping there is a way of getting the file back?

Comment: Is there a system admin, or is that you? Linux does not keep backups of files by default. Your copy from last night may be your best bet.

Comment: Does `notepad++` run on *nix or were you editing the file on Windows?

Comment: notepad++ was on Windows - I have checked the backups for notepad++ and it isn't there and I cant find the recovery directory on my PC

Comment: So what makes you think it will be available on the remote? What you describe sounds like a failed transfer. What old versions would these be?

Comment: For that matter did you close the finished file in Notepad++?  If you reopen it Notepad++ will display the files you had open as tabs.  Is the file you lost a tab name?

Comment: The original file was on the Centos server which I downloaded, edited and then attempted to reupload at which time it got overwritten with a blank file

Comment: Retire FTP and use git.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a Window's question, given it has more to do with Notepad++'s abilities, if any, to maintain any backups of files that you're working on. I'm sorry to say that if you've overridden the file using an FTP client then it's gone on the CentOS side.

You're only option looks to be if you're lucky enough to have Notepad++ setup so that it's maintaining backups for you. It appears to have some facilities around this. This Super User Q&A titled: [Does Notepad++ backup pre-edited files anywhere?](https://superuser.com/questions/281776/does-notepad-backup-pre-edited-files-anywhere) might offer you some tips on how to recover this file, if Notepad++ has kept it for you. But you're essentially out of luck otherwise.

Go to: *Settings* -> *Preferences* -> *Backup*

[image: ss#1]